# Running process AsJob losing information

Tags: powershell, jobs

I have a script that gets the last login information for any given service tag. I run this virtually every day for deployment. After reading about jobs, I figured it'd be worth writing the process as a job. The script I wrote works in that it returns information. When comparing the results of both scripts, I realized that the script that runs the command as a job doesn't return information on every computer in the list of computers.

This is the error I'm getting. It appears to return this against every machine, but then still provides information for most of them. 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E8IR.png)

The old script returns information on every computer in the list.

```
#Load Active Directory 
Import-Module activedirectory
#Load list of computers
$Results = @()
$Computer = Get-Content -path 'C:\Scripts\computers.txt'

#Check each computer in the list 
ForEach($ComputerName in $Computer)
    {
    $results += Get-ADComputer -Filter " Name -Like '*$ComputerName*' " -Properties name, samaccountname, lastlogondate, DNSHostName; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 
     } 

#Export to CSV file
$Results | Select Name, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, DNSHostName | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\Scripts\output.csv'
```

The new script doesn't return information on all of the machines even though it's running virtually the same command just differently.

```
#Check each computer in the list 
Write-Host -Foreground Green "Getting last logon information"
foreach($ComputerName in $Computer)
    {
    Start-Job C:\Scripts\GetADComputer.ps1 -ArgumentList $ComputerName
}
    #Wait for jobs
    Get-Job | Wait-Job

    #Get job results
    $Results += Get-Job | Receive-Job

#Export to CSV file
$Results | Select Name, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, DNSHostName | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\Scripts\output1.csv'
```

The script it calls when it starts the job is:

```
#Allows the $ComputerName variable from the initial script to be used. 
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName
)

#Load Active Directory 
Import-Module activedirectory

#Retrieves information about the ADComputers
Get-ADComputer -Filter " Name -Like '*$ComputerName*' " -Properties name, samaccountname, lastlogondate, DNSHostName; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
```

Anything I can do to prevent information from being lost or is this a side-effect of running something as a job?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_state

Comment: Curious: why are you running a `-Filter` query against AD instead of searching for `-Identity`?

Comment: For how many computers are you doing this?, why are you using jobs instead of a generated filter? can you not do a search based on OU, ADGroup or OS? i have provided an example below which show an alternative way to do what you want.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm currently using filter because of the naming convention we use (it combines site location and machine purpose with service tags). All of the service tags, but not the computer names, of machines that haven't been confirmed as are in a database that I'm able to pull from*.

*I wish I was able to pull directly from the database, but I can get an extract file with all tags in it.

Comment: @SteloNLD It's not exactly a static number of machines that I'm doing this against. It changes week to week, depending on the number of requests for new machines. The minimum tends to be around 20 and the maximum is about 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided in the question could be optimized without using Jobs.

About the issue, i had some issues in the past with creating many jobs and doing a lot of remoting that it would exhaust my network ports or exceed certain maximum connections limits that some applicaties or protocols might have.

Code sample without jobs:

```
### Script Settings/Params

#Computer Names
$ComputerNames = Get-Content -path '.\ComputerNames.txt'

#Computer Properties to retrieve from AD which we want to export.
$ComputerProperties = @('Name', 'SamAccountName', 'LastLogonDate', 'DNSHostName')

#File Path and Name for our export file.
$ExportFilePath = ".\export.csv"

### Script Execution

#AD Query
$ComputerNames_ADFilter = ($ComputerNames | ForEach-Object {"(Name -like '*$($_)*')"}) -join ' -or '
$ADComputers = Get-ADComputer -filter $ComputerNames_ADFilter -Properties $ComputerProperties

#Export
$ADComputers | Select $ComputerProperties | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $ExportFilePath
```

For example if you have the following `@('P-ADDS-','P-SQLS-')` in your `$ServerNames` variable you will get this filter: `(Name -like '*P-ADDS-*') -or (Name -like '*P-SQLS-*')` this would get me all Active Directory and Microsoft SQL related servers in my production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
Regarding the sample above: 

I tried to run this version and I'm getting an error.

`Get-ADComputer : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:19 char:16
+ ... Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter $ComputerNames_ADFilter -Propertie ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer`

Comment: I changed: `$ComputerNames_ADFilter = ($ComputerNames | ForEach-Object {"(Name -eq '$($_)')"}) -join ' -or '`


To: `$ComputerNames_ADFilter = ($ComputerNames | ForEach-Object {"(Name -Like '$($_)')"}) -join ' -or '`

Because my computer file doesn't have the full names of these computers (see earlier comment on naming conventions) 

Though I tried it both ways and got the same error.

Comment: @jfmc dont forget to add the `*` character to the filter when using `-like` example: `"(Name -like '*$($_)*')"` i also changed the answer to better reflect your question, i tested this on powershell 5+ which version are you on?

Comment: Good catch. I did forget that. Even after fixing that. 

`Get-ADComputer : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:20 char:16
+ ... Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter $ComputerNames_ADFilter -Propertie ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer`

Comment: I am on version 5 running it like this `$ComputerNames_ADFilter = ($ComputerNames | ForEach-Object {"(Name -like '*$($_)*')"}) -join ' -or '
$ADComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter $ComputerNames_ADFilter -Properties $ComputerProperties`

Comment: I made an update to the answer, it should work, please run the code line by line and check the variables, i could only replicate this issue when the '$ServerNames' variable was empty, but some special characters in your `'.\ComputerNames.txt'` file could also be the issue, make sure the filter looks like the filter as shown in the answer.

Comment: I'll try running this line by line tomorrow. Work got busy today.